# I am getting "Requested URL not found..." error with cURL. Any ideas?

Tags: php, redirect, curl

So I am posting data to another system and am wanting to retrieve the "redirection url" that the system responds back with and redirect the user after 2 seconds but I get:

> The requested URL /somescript.aspx was not found on this server.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Or is there something else at play?

```
<?php 
$strURL = 'http://someplace.com/somescript.aspx'; 
$fields_string = implode('&', (array)$_SESSION['apply']);

$resURL = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($resURL, CURLOPT_URL, $strURL); 
curl_setopt($resURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($resURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($resURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($resURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
$response = curl_exec($resURL); 
$RedirectLocation = curl_getinfo($resURL, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

unset($_SESSION['apply']); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "<?php echo $RedirectLocation; ?>";
    }, 2000)
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're looking to retrieve the 301/302 redirect target, but not actually follow it? Set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true, and parse the `Location:` header out of the response.

To see what I mean change your code to this:

```
curl_setopt($resURL,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER);
$response = curl_exec($resURL); 
echo $repsonse
```

IIRC `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` won't change if you don't set curl to follow redirects.

Comment: Great.  I will try that.  But will that fix/correct the "requested url" error?